# Blender 2.9 (and 3.0) Bone Name and Constraint Issues (Solved)

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, rigging, bones, error

Blender 2.93.4 and 3.0.0

Issues:

**Inverse Kinematics Bone Constraint** applies to the **Wrong Bone** (AKA any Bone but the Selected Bone)

**Bone Name** is applied to the **Wrong Bone** and **Bone Information** is not shown in the **Right Side Tab** (Information is the same no matter which bone is selected/Bone Information is not updated with bone selection)

-Both Problems are present in both **Edit and Pose Mode**

-Both Problems are present with any **New or Pre-Made Rig**

-Both Problems are present in any **.blend File**

I am not well versed with Blender Rigs and I have just started learning Bone Constraints like Inverse Kinematics so I haven’t been able to find a working solution or a root cause on my own unfortunately.
__

Solved:

-User Error - was using the box select tool

__

**Photos of Issues Below**

[image: Bone Name Issue]

[image: Inverse Kinematics Bone Issue]

Comment: The current version of Blender 2.93 is 2.93.9 so it might be worth updating to that [here](https://www.blender.org/download/lts/2-93/) to see if any bugs have been fixed if you can't use a later version.

Comment: It appears that you had both "New" and "Bone.001" selected when you added the IK constraint; but since you had selected "New" last, making it the active bone, the IK constraint was applied to it.  Not a bug. Try deselecting all (ALT-A) and then select just one bone.  The IK constraint should apply properly.

Comment: @MartyFouts You were correct that it was a user error. I was selecting the bones with the box select tool and I guess Blender doesn’t count that as an actual selection for bones and sticks to the last selected. Glad it was just user error lol.

Comment: Box select adds to the selection, so you probably had one bone selected already; or you managed to draw the box to include both bones.